# Graphs having unique hamiltonian paths between exactly 4 pair of vertices

Tags: graph-theory

Need some example graphs which are not hamiltonian, i.e, does not admit any hamiltonian cycle,  but which have hamiltonian path. It has unique hamiltonian paths between exactly 4 pair of vertices. I have identified one such group of graphs. Would like to see more such examples.

Comment: Why do you need more examples? How'bout the graph with five vertices formed by joining two triangles at one corner? In fact, start with two triangles join them together by a string of edges, and attach to a vertex along the line a complete graph on some number of vertices, voila, infinitely many examples. 

Comment: The first one is not only for triangles, it actually generalizes to a family of graphs and that is exactly the class I have in mind. I would like to see more such "graph families".. preferably construction to generate this kind of graphs. About your next example, I am not very clear. How can you attach a clique at some point on the path between the two triangles? that will form a local loop instead of beoing covered by HP.

Answer (score 2):

This answer elaborates on Willie Wong's comment and also provides another class of examples.  Start with a clique $K_n$, pick two vertices $u, v \in K_n$, and glue two triangles onto $K_n$ at $u$ and $v$.  It is easy to see that for any $n$, this graph
is not Hamiltonian but there do exist exactly four pairs of vertices that are the endpoints of a Hamiltonian path.  Furthermore, instead of using $K_n$, any subgraph such that there exists a Hamiltonian path between the distinguished vertices $u$ and $v$ will still do the trick.

Another class of examples is to take the 4-wheel (a 4-cycle with an apex vertex) and to glue one end of a path onto the hub of the wheel.  Again, there are mutations of this construction.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. It has to have unique hamiltonian paths between exactly 4 pair of vertices. Also, tthe triangles can be generalized as $C_m$ for some $m$